# How do I get an out string parameter from C using Rust's FFI?

Tags: rust, ffi

I've been diving into FFI with Rust, and while there are some useful posts and documentation on passing in strings and sometimes getting a string back as the return value from a C function, I don't see any way to get an out parameter. To get my feet wet, I am trying to access a C library that exposes a function that is declared as:

```c
unsigned char *some_func(
    const unsigned char *key,
    unsigned int klen,
    const unsigned char *src,
    unsigned char *dest,
    unsigned int slen);
```

I think it should be declared roughly as:

```rust
use libc;

extern "C" {
    fn some_func(
        key: *const libc::c_uchar,
        klen: libc::c_uint,
        src: *const libc::c_uchar,
        dest: *mut libc::c_uchar,
        slen: libc::c_uint) -> *mut libc::c_uchar;
}

// wrapper
pub fn wrapped_func(key: &str, src: &str) -> String {
    unsafe {
        let key_len = key.len() as u32;
        let key = std::ffi::CString::new(key).unwrap();

        let src_len = src.len() as u32;
        let src = std::ffi::CString::new(src).unwrap();

        let key_ptr = key.as_ptr();
        let src_ptr = src.as_ptr();

        let mut dest: *mut std::ffi::CStr;

        let result = PC1(key_ptr, key_len, src_ptr, &mut dest, src_len);
        //                                          ^^^^^^^^^ expected `u8`, found *-ptr
        key_ptr = ptr::null();
        src_ptr = ptr::null();

        let result_string = if let Ok(s) = result.to_str() {
           String::from(s)
        } else {
           String::new()
        };

        dest = ptr::null();

        result_string
}
```

There are a few issues I'm having with this:

1. I don't know how to properly declare `dest` as my out string. What's the right way to get an output string? From [Wrapping Unsafe C Libraries in Rust](https://medium.com/dwelo-r-d/wrapping-unsafe-c-libraries-in-rust-d75aeb283c65), it looks like I need to treat this as a `CStr`:

> For cases where you’re getting a `const char *` from a C function and want to convert it to something Rust can use, you’ll need to ensure it’s not null, then convert it into a `&CStr` with an appropriate lifetime. If you can’t figure out how to express an appropriate lifetime, the safest thing is to immediately convert it into an owned `String`!

2. The C code - and therefore my extern function - declares the strings as `unsigned char *`, but when I try to invoke, I have a type mismatch between `u8` and `i8`. Is it acceptable to just switch the `extern` to be `c_char`, or is this dangerous?
3. Is setting `key_ptr = ptr::null()` the correct way (and all that's needed) to release the memory safely?

Comment: Regarding 3): C has no notion of ownership. When a C API hands you a resource back, the responsibilities inherited can only be found in supporting documentation or source code comments. This is implemented on a case-by-case basis, and often requires explicit API calls to release resources. Assigning a null value to a pointer in C has no effect on the pointed-to resource. The assignment may act as a sentinel, but is never part of the actual resource management.

Comment: You should probably be using [`rust-bindgen`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen) to generate the proper bindings and automatically generate layout tests.